# node.js - Passport not persisting across browser requests, works with Postman

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js, axios

I am currently using the create-react-app boiler plate and have been attempting to add auth. I am using axios as my promise based HTTP libray with React.js. I have been using node with express, express-session, passport and passport-local on the backend.

Here is my server.js file with some exlusions:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// Express only serves static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));

app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'topsecretpassword',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    originalMaxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


// Setup Database connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  user : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'mvy_db'
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?', user, function(err, userId) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Database Error',
        id: userId[0]
      });
    }

    done(err, userId[0]);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  },
  function(email, password, done) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?', email, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user.length) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
      }
      if (user[0].password !== password) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user[0]);
    });
  }
));

app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.session);
  return res.send('login success!');
});

function isAuthenticated (req,res,next){
  console.log(req.session);
  if(req.session.passport.user)
     return next();
  else
     return res.status(401).json({
       error: 'User not authenticated'
     })

}

app.get('/checkauth', isAuthenticated, function(req,res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'User Authenticated!'
  });
})

app.get('/signout', function(req,res) {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.status(200).json({ success: 'successfully signed out' });
})
```

Using postman (and even on the browser), I am able to successfully login and the following is held in the req.session object :

```
   cookie:
    { path: '/',
      _expires: null,
      originalMaxAge: 86400000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false },
      passport: { user: 1 } }
```

my login request using axios:

```
return axios.post(ROOT_URL + 'signin', {
      email: e.target.email.value,
      password: e.target.password.value
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
```

My checkAuth request using axios (this is where I get a 500 error returned):

```
  axios.get(ROOT_URL + 'checkauth', { withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

The req.session object after checking authentication before the error message, note that the passport object doesn't exist anymore:

```
 Session {
   cookie:
    { path: '/',
      _expires: null,
      originalMaxAge: 86400000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false } }
```

This is the error message I get on the console when I attempt to check that the user is authorized:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
     at isAuthenticated (/server.js:94:26)
```

I've been banging my head for hours, trying to resolve this issue. I thought it might have something to do with CORS, but after hours of playing around with it that doesn't seem to be the case. It's still plausible that it's a CORS issue, but what's really flustering me is that it works full well with Postman but not on my Chrome browser. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so I found the solution to my problem. It appeared to be an issue with axios and the configuration of my get requests. For some reason, using the structure `axios.get(URL) .then(response)` doesn't work with the withCredentials property.

Instead, I had to send my request as:

`axios(ROOT_URL + 'checkauth', { 
      method: 'get',
      withCredentials: true 
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });`

Comment: This worked for me as well, and FYI I was originally using `axios.post` and switched to `axios({ method: post... }) with success. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Oh because I forgot that axious doesn’t send credentials by default I had to stick with jwt and completely removed session.

You can define an instance of axious which will allow you to make requests much more simply

```
const $axios = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  withCredentials: true
});
```